# When mysql_real_escape_string() is needed?

Tags: php

Is `mysql_real_escape_string()` with `sprintf` needed only at login page or at every `mysql_query` after login, for preventing SQL injection?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use mysql_real_escape_string for any user supplied data that is going to be ran through an SQL query.

Comment: More likely, you shouldn't be using `mysql_*` at all.

Comment: This is true as of today, not so much two years ago. :D

Answer (score 6):

You should use mysql_real_escape_string() every time you insert user-posted data into a query, or use a database wrapper like [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) that can do prepared statements. That would be better, because they do the job of sanitizing for you.

If you are working on the overall security of your site, this is great and definitely necessary. If you are looking for reasons why your site was hacked, though, I doubt this was done through a SQL injection, as your actual HTML code was affected (or so I thought, I may be wrong). This would be only possible if you had your FTP password stored somewhere in the database.

Answer (score 3):

Use it when you do not trust the **input**. And **never trust a user input.**

Answer (score -1):

In **any** instance that you accept user input, you should use [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) on it before sending it to the database. It is a good idea to use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) on the input as well.

Comment: I take it the -1 was for recommending mysql_real_escape_string. Fixed